# Shiny App CSS Styling File not being applied on shiny server instance

Tags: css, r, shiny, shiny-server

I've deployed a shiny app on my company's AWS servers. The shiny app is running on an EC2 instance, so I have access to the folder structure. I managed to drop a reference file for connectivity in the folder the shiny app is in, an I can succesfully call elements from that file.
I recently created a custom css styling file, which I tested on an online RStudio version. It's supposed to customise the header, sidebar, some buttons and the content boxes. It works almost perfectly on RStudio, but when I copied it to the EC2 instance and call it the same way in the shiny app, it seems to not make use of the elements at all.

Here's an exerpt of the css file:

```r
/* Get a fancy font from Google Fonts */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Yusei+Magic&display=swap');


/* header title font */
.main-header .logo {
  font-family: "Lato", normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
}


/* background color of header (logo part) */
.skin-blue .main-header .logo {
          background-color: #7f308a;
        }
        
        
/* change the background color of header (logo part) when mouse hover */
.skin-blue .main-header .logo:hover {
          background-color: #7f308a;
        }
        

/* background color for remaining part of the header */
.skin-blue .main-header .navbar {
                              background-color: #772583;
                              } 
                              
/* main sidebar */
        .skin-blue .main-sidebar {
                              background-color: #504f54;
                              color: white ;
                              }

/* active sidebar menu item */
        .skin-blue .main-sidebar .sidebar .sidebar-menu .active a{
                              background-color: #ED9128;
                              color: white;
                              }

/* sidebar menuitems */
        .skin-blue .main-sidebar .sidebar .sidebar-menu a{
                              background-color: #504f54;
                              color: white;
                              }

/* sidebar menuitems when mouse hover */
.skin-blue .main-sidebar .sidebar .sidebar-menu a:hover {
    background-color: #f2ab5a!important;
    color: #ffffff!important;
}
```

I reference the file in the shiny app code as follows:

```r
ui <- dashboardPage(
                    dashboardHeader(title = "mytitle"),
                    dashboardSidebar(
                      sidebarMenu(
                        menuItem("tab1", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("clock")),
                        menuItem("tab2", tabName = "ehl", icon = icon("graduation-cap"))
                      )
                    ),
                    dashboardBody(
                      tags$style(
                        tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "custom.css")),
                      tags$head(
                        tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "custom.css")),
                      tags$header(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "custom.css"))
))
```

I can post more code if necessary, but I'm quite puzzled as to why it just seems to ignore the file or its elements completely on the app I deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out in my case that I had to create the 'www' directory/folder where my app.R was, and drop the .css file in there. Now it works